# |psi|^2 calculation (1D) for diamond structure silicon not showing full dataset for all bands: Quantum ESPRESSO

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, charge-density, wavefunctions

Dear Quantum ESPRESSO users,
I was trying to calculate the |psi|^2 calculation (1D) for diamond structure silicon at a single kpoint (gamma point). I have used the semicore pseudopotential that consists of 12 electrons (anyone can use non-semicore pseudopotential with 4 electrons too). After scf and pp.x post processing calculations done (both shows **JOB DONE** in the output files - indicating successful job run), I see that there are twelve band files generated for 1D plot (|psi|^2 vs r). My concern is, I see that the distance (r) column of first band file extends from 0 to 41.45 alat, while the other bands (2-12) extend from 0 to 1 alat. I am not sure why they are showing full data set for the first band file only and stopping at exactly 1 alat for the other bands. Could you please inform me the possible reason for this, and way to solve it so that I can get the full data set (r value from 0 to 41.45 alat) for all twelve bands?

I am sending the scf and pp.x input files, and their outputs below for convenience.

Hope to get your cordial cooperation to solve this.

**SCF (pw.x) input file:**

```
&control
   prefix = 'silicon'
   calculation = 'scf'
   restart_mode = 'from_scratch'
   wf_collect = .false.
   tstress = .true.
   tprnfor = .true.
   outdir = './'
   wfcdir = './'
   pseudo_dir = './'
   verbosity = 'low'
/
&system
   ibrav = 2
   celldm(1) = 10.33517
   nat = 2
   ntyp = 1
   ecutwfc = 150,
   occupations='smearing',
   smearing='gaussian',
   degauss=0.022,
/
&electrons
   electron_maxstep = 100
   conv_thr = 1.0d-10
   mixing_mode = 'plain'
   mixing_beta = 0.7
   mixing_ndim = 8
   diagonalization = 'david'
   diago_david_ndim = 4
   diago_full_acc = .true.
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
  Si  28.086  Si.upf
ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
  Si  -0.125000000  -0.125000000  -0.125000000
  Si   0.125000000   0.125000000   0.125000000
K_POINTS automatic
8 8 8 0 0 0
```

**Post-processing (pp.x) input file:**

```
&INPUTPP
  prefix="silicon"
  outdir="./"
  filplot="psi2_e3_f"
  plot_num=7
  kband(1)=1
  kband(2)=12
  kpoint(1)=1
/
&PLOT
  nfile = 1
  iflag = 1
  output_format = 0
  fileout = ".gnu"
x0(1)=0.375
x0(2)=0.125
x0(3)=0.625
e1(1)=12.5
e1(2)=37.5
e1(3)=-12.5
nx=10000
/
```

**First 10 lines of band-1 file (extends from 0 to 41.45 alat, with 10000 data row):**
more psi2_e3_f_K001_B001.gnu

```
        0.0000000000        0.5774665488
        0.0041461956        0.5739151472
        0.0082923912        0.5633830748
        0.0124385868        0.5462309811
        0.0165847824        0.5230407530
        0.0207309780        0.4945872344
        0.0248771736        0.4618000344
        0.0290233693        0.4257172175
        0.0331695649        0.3874334770
        0.0373157605        0.3480461457
```

**Last 10 lines of band-1 file (extends from 0 to 41.45 alat, with 10000 data row):**
cat psi2_e3_f_K001_B001.gnu

```
       41.4204941190        0.0000000001
       41.4246403146        0.0000000001
       41.4287865102        0.0000000000
       41.4329327058        0.0000000000
       41.4370789014        0.0000000000
       41.4412250970        0.0000000000
       41.4453712926        0.0000000000
       41.4495174882        0.0000000000
       41.4536636838        0.0000000000
       41.4578098794        0.0000000000
```

**First 10 lines of band-2 file (extends from 0 to 1 alat, with 10000 data row):**
more psi2_e3_f_K001_B002.gnu

```
        0.0000000000       -0.0000000000
        0.0001000100        0.0000000712
        0.0002000200        0.0000002849
        0.0003000300        0.0000006413
        0.0004000400        0.0000011403
        0.0005000500        0.0000017822
        0.0006000600        0.0000025670
        0.0007000700        0.0000034948
        0.0008000800        0.0000045656
        0.0009000900        0.0000057795
```

**Last 10 lines of band-2 file (extends from 0 to 1 alat, with 10000 data row):**
cat psi2_e3_f_K001_B002.gnu

```
        0.9990999100        0.0070165649
        0.9991999200        0.0070205456
        0.9992999300        0.0070245267
        0.9993999400        0.0070285081
        0.9994999500        0.0070324898
        0.9995999600        0.0070364717
        0.9996999700        0.0070404539
        0.9997999800        0.0070444361
        0.9998999900        0.0070484185
        1.0000000000        0.0070524009
```

For **B003-B012**.gnu files, the data stops at **1 alat**, similarly like psi2_e3_f_K001_B002.gnu file. They should stop at **41.45 alat**, similarly like  psi2_e3_f_K001_B001.gnu file to make a consistent calculation output.

[The full output data is not supported here to paste (due to character limit). So I pasted here the first and last 10 lines for each of the two files, and mentioned the number of data row for both files.]

Comment: Welcome to the site! Would you be able to add the data from the attached images as text. This makes it easier for other users to analyze, especially those that use screen readers.

Comment: Hi Tyberius, thanks for your comment. The input commands are used as data/code format. Only the screenshot of the output is given - which can be ignored to see, as the text already describes the fact of the output.

Comment: Sak, what do you mean that "only the screenshot of the output is given" ? Do you not have the file `psi2_e3_f_K001_B001.gnu`? I agree with @Tyberius that it is absolutely preferable to have the text output rather than a screenshot. You might have to search on Google how to copy and paste from a terminal?

Comment: Thank you very much @Tyberius. I have updated the output images to pasting the data, as suggested.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nike Dattani. I have updated the output images to pasting the data, as suggested. I am not sure if you were asking the full data set (which have 10,000 row of data for each of the 12 output files I was getting), but I pasted the first and last 10 output data of two files of interest (to get ideas where it starts and where it stops, and how many data row they have).

Comment: @Sak if you want to add 12 files with 10,000 rows each, you can push them to [this Git repository](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/Modeling_Matters) in a folder called 9383 since that is the number in this question's URL.

Comment: Actually I don't want to add 12 output files unless otherwise the problem is unsolvable. The input files are fully given and the output file portions are given as well. I can still upload those huge output file if you feel that only then you can solve it (though the issue should be solved from input file modification). @Nike Dattani

Comment: Did you figure out the answer to this? Are you still working on it?

Comment: It's not figured out yet in a concrete way. But whenever I start with later bands, it shows full data for the starting band file only. So I had to change the starting band for each calculation and then it solved. But I was thinking to get it solved with one single job command. @NikeDattani

Comment: So it's now possible to get what you want if you change the starting band for each calculation, and this was not possible before? Now you you'd also like to find out a way to do it with just one job rather than several calculations?

Comment: Yes...I will be checking that. Primarily it looks like a bug, as it prints full data for only the starting band file, depending on what is the starting band command in the input file. I think, as it is solved in the way described above, the question status can be turned to solved or closed. @Nike

Comment: Would you be able to write an answer with your current solution? That's the best way to mark the question as solved for now!